# how to read a part of line in a txt file in c++

Tags: c++, text-files

I am trying to read a portion of a line in a text file.
the text file contains the number of the movies, how many award it has, how many times has the movie been nominated to the award, and the movie name. the text file looks like this:

```
2

1935 1 3

The Dark Angel

1935 4 6

The Informer
```

I tried to use the getline() function, but when i compile it, there is nothing but junk values.

Here is the code I have written

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    ifstream infile;
    int numofmovies;
    infile.open("old_movies.txt");
    infile >> numofmovies;
    int numawards[numofmovies], nomination[numofmovies], year[numofmovies];
    string moviename[numofmovies];
    for (int i = 0 ; i < numofmovies ; i++)
    {
        infile >> year[i] >> numawards[i] >> nomination[i];
        getline(infile, moviename[i]);

        cout <<moviename[i]<< endl;


    }
    return 0;

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can't compile:

```
int numawards[numofmovies], nomination[numofmovies], year[numofmovies];
```

`numofmovies` is not a constant, compile time value, so you cannot use it to declare arrays like that. You should use vector.

```
std::vector<int> numawards(numofmovies);
std::vector<int> nomination(numofmovies);
std::vector<int> year(numofmovies);
std::vector<std::string> moviename(numofmovies);
```

BTW, why don't you declare a type `Movie` like this:

```
struct Movie
{
   std::string name;
   int numawards;
   int nominations;
   int year;
}
```

And then use it to read your data:

```
std::vector<Movie> movies(numofmovies);

for (int i = 0 ; i < numofmovies ; i++)
{
    infile >> movies[i].year >> movies[i].numawards >> movies[i].nomination;
    getline(infile, movies[i].moviename);

    cout <<movies[i].moviename<< endl;
}
```

Comment: Are there any alternative ways to do this without using vectors? Because my professor has completely skipped the vector topic. Thanks

Comment: @CowEarsGrass you can simply use a local variable in this for loop since you just print it. Feel free to do so if you don't have any other use of this data.

Comment: @CowEatsGrass "my professor has completely skipped the vector topic" - that should be a testimonial to consider. With the possible exception of `std::string`, the class template `std::vector<>` is easily the most often utilized template in the entire standard C++ library, and *both* would play together nicely with this assignment. If the instructor hasn't covered it yet, ask *when* he/she *will* cover it, and gauge the response to that question carefully, whatever it is.

Comment: @CowEatsGrass learn what the professors teach you and you will never be able program.